# Trouble creating array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array and I want to pick 3 of its elements and put store it in another array as a single object and again repeatedly follow the same process on every 3 elements of the array. This is my code below:

```js
let breakpoints = [
  {name: "from-amonut", value: "100"},
  {name: "to-amonut", value: "200"},
  {name: "gst", value: "10"},
  {name: "from-amonut", value: "200"},
  {name: "to-amonut", value: "300"},
  {name: "gst", value: "20"},
  {name: "from-amonut", value: "300"},
  {name: "to-amonut", value: "400"},
  {name: "gst", value: "30"}
];

let temp = {
  "from_amount": 0,
  "to_amount": 0,
  "gst": 0
};

let formattedBreakpoints = [];

breakpoints.map((v, k) => {
  (v.name == "from-amonut") ? temp.from_amount = v.value: "";
  (v.name == "to-amonut") ? temp.to_amount = v.value: "";
  (v.name == "gst") ? temp.gst = v.value: "";
  ((k + 1) % 3 === 0) ? (formattedBreakpoints.push(temp), console.log(temp)) : "";

});
console.log(formattedBreakpoints);
```

I'm expecting `formattedBreakpoints` to be `[{"from_amount":100, "to_amount":200, "gst":10}, {"from_amount":200, "to_amount":300, "gst":20}.....]` but only returns all the objects with the value of last array elements.

Comment: Your result array consists of references to the **same** object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to add all properties to the last object. Whenever the index (`i`) remainder from 3 is 0, you add another object to the accumulator.

```js
const breakpoints = [{"name":"from-amonut","value":"100"},{"name":"to-amonut","value":"200"},{"name":"gst","value":"10"},{"name":"from-amonut","value":"200"},{"name":"to-amonut","value":"300"},{"name":"gst","value":"20"},{"name":"from-amonut","value":"300"},{"name":"to-amonut","value":"400"},{"name":"gst","value":"30"}];
        
const result = breakpoints.reduce((r, { name, value }, i) => {
  if(i % 3 === 0) r.push({});
  
  const key = name.replace(/-/g, '_');

  r[r.length - 1][key] = value;
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

What's the problem in your code is the reuse of `temp`. Since temp is an object, pushing it to the array, adds the reference to the array, and doesn't create a new object. To prevent that, you can init `temp` whenever you get to the last property. You should also use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (do something with value) instead of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (create new array with items based on original values).

```js
const breakpoints = [{"name":"from-amonut","value":"100"},{"name":"to-amonut","value":"200"},{"name":"gst","value":"10"},{"name":"from-amonut","value":"200"},{"name":"to-amonut","value":"300"},{"name":"gst","value":"20"},{"name":"from-amonut","value":"300"},{"name":"to-amonut","value":"400"},{"name":"gst","value":"30"}];

let temp = {};

const formattedBreakpoints = [];

breakpoints.forEach((v, k) => {
  if(v.name == "from-amonut") temp.from_amount = v.value;
  if(v.name == "to-amonut") temp.to_amount = v.value;
  if(v.name == "gst") { // whenever we get to gst, we can push to array, and reset temp
    temp.gst = v.value;
    formattedBreakpoints.push(temp);
    temp = {};
  };
});
console.log(formattedBreakpoints);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! But could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: oh! okay. But when I'm displaying `temp` just after pushing it into an array, I'm getting the correct object displayed in the console.

Comment: Indeed, but you also changed all the previous items, because you are pointing to the same reference. Console log `formattedBreakpoints` after each step, and you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code that you are mutating a single object temp and pushing it 3 times to the result array. So what's going on:

1. You are creating an object
2. In a map method you are mutating it repeatedly and after every 3 iterations you are setting reference to this object to the result array.

Key word here is `reference`. That means that this is the same object. For example:

```
const result = [];
const obj = {};

obj.a = 'a';
result.push(obj); // => result = [{ a: 'a' }]

obj.b = 'b';
result.push(obj); // => result = [{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }, { a: 'a', b: 'b' }]
```

Try this way:

```
let formattedBreakpoints = [];
for (let i = 0; i < breakpoints.length; i += 3) {
  const breakPointOptions = breakpoints.slice(i, i + 3);
  formattedBreakpoints.push(breakPointOptions.reduce((result, { name, value }) => {
    result[name] = value;
    return result;
  }, {}));
}
```

Comment: This works! But could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: @zainulabdeen added detailed explanation

Comment: So you mean we cannot override an object the way we normally do with a variable?

Comment: @zainulabdeen you can, it you reassign your object variable with a new object.

Comment: okay, Thank you so much for your Help. Actually, all the answers to this question are correct. But I can only mark 1 answer as accepted. So I marked the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let breakpoints = [
       {name: "from-amonut", value: "100"},
       {name: "to-amonut", value: "200"},
       {name: "gst", value: "10"},
       {name: "from-amonut", value: "200"},
       {name: "to-amonut", value: "300"},
       {name: "gst", value: "20"},
       {name: "from-amonut", value: "300"},
       {name: "to-amonut", value: "400"},
       {name: "gst", value: "30"}
      ]
      let temp = {
       "from_amount" : 0,
       "to_amount" : 0,
       "gst" : 0
      };
      let formattedBreakpoints = [];
      breakpoints.map((v, k)=>{
       (v.name == "from-amonut") ? temp.from_amount = v.value : "";
       (v.name == "to-amonut") ? temp.to_amount = v.value : "";
       (v.name == "gst") ? temp.gst = v.value : "";
       ((k + 1) % 3 === 0) ? (formattedBreakpoints.push(temp), temp = {... temp}) : "" ;
       
      });
      console.log(formattedBreakpoints);
```

As `temp` is an object you are **using it by reference**. So you need to create a new object each time you push or else the same object will be referenced. Hence I'm using `temp` itself to create this new object.